# Quote about being cautious when trying to change the future

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

In *Revenge of the Sith*, Anakin tries to prevent the death of Padme - predicted in his force visions.

Upon consulting one of the Jedi Masters, this master advises Anakin to be careful about trying to change the future. The very actions someone may take to prevent one version of the future, might be the very actions that lead to the feature that was meant to be avoided.

Does anybody know, the exact quote and who said it? I always thought it is a beautiful quote and it turned out to be true in that exact case.

If I had to guess, I would say the Master in question was Yoda. The meaning relates to his quote "Difficult to see. Always in motion is the future." in *The Empire Strikes Back*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you're talking about scene 77, with Anakin in conversation with Yoda.

> 77 INT. CORUSCANT-JEDI TEMPLE-YODAS QUARTERS-DAY
>
> YODA and ANAKIN sit in Yoda's room, deep in thought.
>
> YODA: Premonitions... premonitions... Hmmmm... these visions you have...
>
> ANAKIN: They are of pain, suffering, death...
>
> YODA: Yourself you speak of, or someone you know?
>
> ANAKIN: Someone...
>
> YODA: ...close to you?
>
> ANAKIN: Yes.
>
> YODA: Careful you must be when sensing the future, Anakin. The fear of loss is a path to the dark side.
>
> ANAKIN: I won't let these visions come true, Master Yoda.
>
> YODA: Death is a natural part of life. Rejoice for those around you who transform into the Force. Mourn them, do not. Miss them, do not. Attachment leads to jealousy. The shadow of greed, that is.
>
> ANAKIN: What must I do, Master Yoda?
>
> YODA: Train yourself to let go of everything you fear to lose.

It speaks to accepting the future, but not the danger of creating the future you're trying to avoid.  I don't recall that specific warning in any of the prequel movies.

Comment: I found this quote too. But I am pretty sure, there was a quote specifically warning about the "I won't let these visions come true" part. Because trying might only enable the vision to become true.

Comment: Are you sure you're not conflating it with Yoda's warning to Luke in Ep. V?  "YODA: Decide you must how to serve them best. If you leave now, help them you could. But you would destroy all for which they have fought and suffered."  I searched the transcripts for all the movies (even Ep. IV-VI, which I didn't really need to), and didn't find a quote closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Just skimmed through the movie up to the duel between Darth Sidious and Mace Windu and could not find my quote. So I guess, I have mixed up the three quotes mentioned above or took it from a different story. Thanks for the invested time

Comment: I remember one along those lines from a different story. In the novel  Cyteen, by CJ Cherryh, Ariane Emory says "There was a man who could see the future. He tried to change it. But that **was** his future."